# JSON.parse() with multiple requessts $.get()

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, laravel, get

In this code Jquery I make two calls $ .get () using the $ .when (). The problem occurs when using JSON.parse (). If I make a single call, and then only one variable, it's all right, but when both are called is as if the execution of JSON.parse () was blocked and the console shows me this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" in .

How could I solve? Thanks for the help possible. Here is the code:

```
function carica_commenti(id)
{  
    var pagina = $('#pagina'+id).val();   

    $.when($.get("/carica_commenti_ajax/"+id+"/"+pagina), $.get("/post/commenti/apprezzamenti_commenti")).done(function(commenti, app) 
    {
            var commento = JSON.parse(commenti); 
            var apprezzamenti = JSON.parse(app);  

            var resultHtml = '';           

            $.each(commento, function(i, el) 
            {                
                resultHtml +=   "<div class='commento' id='commento"+ el.id_comments +  "'>\
                                    <a href='goak.it/utente/"+ el.id_user +"/1'>\
                                        <img src='//goak.it/"+ el.percorso +"'width=30px and height=30px/>\
                                        <strong>"+ el.nome +" "+ el.cognome +"</strong>\
                                    </a>\
                                    <span id='corpo-commento"+ el.id_comments +"'>"+ el.contenuto +"</span>\
                                    <div class='post-modifica btn-group'> \
                                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-post btn-default dropdown-toggle post-tasti-modifica tasto-commento' data-toggle='dropdown'>\
                                            <span class='caret'></span>\
                                        </button>\
                                        <ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu'>\
                                            <li><a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modifica-commento'  class='modifica-commento' id='"+ el.id_comments +  "'>Modifica Commento</a></li>\
                                            <li><a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#cancella-commento' class='cancella-commento' id='"+ el.id_comments +  "'>Cancella Commento</a></li>\
                                        </ul>\
                                    </div>\
                                </div>\
                                <div class='info-notifica data-commento'>\
                                    <time class='timeago'> Adesso · </time>\
                                    <a class='mi-interessa-commento' id='like_commento"+ el.id_comments +  "' onclick='like_commento("+ el.id_comments +")' value='1'> Mi interessa </a>\
                                </div>";


            });

            $('#commentscontainer'+id).append(resultHtml);
        });    
        var $input = $('#pagina'+id);
        $input.val( +$input.val() + 1 );
}
```

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" in  <!doctype html>

Comment: Take a look into the network tab of your browsers dev console. What is the response the server sent? It looks a lot like JSON.parse is trying to parse an error message formatted as HTML or XML...

Comment: Try to log the value of `app` and `commenti` to the console : I suspect one of them is an HTML string representation, hence the leading `<`.

Comment: check what is `commenti`...  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/#example-0  `Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]`

Comment: Just checked . Both calls return an array. The error " Uncaught SyntaxError : Unexpected token < " is associated with " < ! Doctype html > "

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters `commenti` and `app` are indeed arrays, but with the structure of an ajax response : `[ data, statusText, jqXHR ]`.

So, if you want to parse the result of your call, you have to call `JSON.parse()` on the `data`, not on the entire array.

[See an example from jQuery's docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/#example-0) :

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) ).done(function( a1, a2 ) {
  // a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively.
  // Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]
  var data = a1[ 0 ] + a2[ 0 ]; // a1[ 0 ] = "Whip", a2[ 0 ] = " It"
  if ( /Whip It/.test( data ) ) {
    alert( "We got what we came for!" );
  }
});
```

Comment: What I do not get is that the error on the call. Ie in the $ .when ( )

Comment: @francisco I sincerely don't understand your sentence... Can you reformulate?

Comment: Excuse me . The error is generated inside the function $.when() but if you are using two calls $.get() and then two variables . If using only one call and one variable is all ok .